# Use of unassigned local variable '_tr'

Tags: c#, windows, try-catch

```
bool _Error = false;
ThesResult _tr;
try { _tr = engine["en"].LookupSynonyms(_Word, true); }
catch (Exception)
{
    _Error = true;
}
if (_Error)
{
    _Synonyms.Add(word);
}
else
{
     List<string> SynonymNew = new List<string>();
     foreach (ThesMeaning meaning in _tr.Meanings)
```

The error occurs at the bottom line _tr.Meanings. I have no idea how to fix this, everything seems to be OK logically but I need to find a way to make the compiler see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `_tr` to `null` when you declare it. The compiler sees that there's a chance it may not have been initialised.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go ahead and say that perhaps you might want to re-think your order of operations. `try... catch (set flag) if(flag)` is close to an anti-pattern. There are several good reasons for doing this:

- It is not the clearest way to write the code
- You aren't allocating extra memory this way
- You are using one fewer variables (my guess is that _Error is not used elsewhere)

  ```
  bool _Error = false;
  // ThesResult _tr; <!-- only needed in the try block.
  try { 
      ThesResult _tr = engine["en"].LookupSynonyms(_Word, true); 
      List<string> SynonymNew = new List<string>();
      // no worries about initializing it to null.
      foreach (ThesMeaning meaning in _tr.Meanings)
      // your loop and the rest of the function.
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
      _Synonyms.Add(word); // is this supposed to be _Word?
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You must assign the value of **_tr** before using it. If you want to drink water from a recipient with no water, then you are not drinking anything, are you?

In the try part of your code it cannot guarantee that it will get a value for **_tr** , so you must initialize your variable yourself before using it, at least with null.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to assign `null` to objects at least before using them:

```
 bool _Error = false;
 ThesResult _tr = null;
 try { _tr = engine["en"].LookupSynonyms(_Word, true); }
 catch (Exception)
       {
          _Error = true;
       }
       if (_Error)
       {
           _Synonyms.Add(word);
       }
       else
         {
                    List<string> SynonymNew = new List<string>();
                    foreach (ThesMeaning meaning in _tr.Meanings)
```

Answer (score 1):

C# requires that you guarantee that a variable has been assigned a value before trying to use it. In this case, if the `LookupSynonyms` method throws an exception, then `_tr` will never get a value, not even `null`.

So it won't let you compile unless you can guarantee that you've at least assigned something (even `null`) to the variable before you use it.

This is unlike some other languages (VB) which automatically initialize a variable to its default value (like null or zero or whatever), or other languages (C++) which the variable starts out as garbage (whatever happened to be in that memory address at the time).

Answer (score 0):

When initializing set _tr = null

```
ThesResult _tr = null;
```